# Sending email to multiple recipients

Tags: gmail

I need to use my Note 10.1 to send an email to multiple recipients in the cc or bcc field. But it seems I cannot copy and paste the contacts which are automatically put into the 'to' field. Gmail in android also seems to allow only 250 contacts to be emailed at the same time.

Is there a way to copy and paste the contacts from the 'to' field into the 'cc' field? And send more than 250 emails at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: Frankly, if you need to send email to that many recipients on a repeated basis, you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you frequently need to send these mails to the same large groups of people, have you thought about using Contact Groups, so that you only need to add and remove that group from the To or CC fields, rather than constantly dealing with huge numbers of names?

Creating the groups is easiest to do and manage in the web version of GMail (which you can use from your tablet). See [GMail Help -> Creating Contact Groups](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30970?hl=en) for more info on this.

Comment: I have contact groups. But cannot send emails to more than 250 contacts in any group at the same time using android gmail.