# Send email by selecting multiple users from Contacts app

Tags: contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean, gmail, htc-one-x, htc-sense

When I need to send email to multiple users in Gmail app I explicitly need to type in their addresses. Is there any way to select multiple users from my Contacts app and put them into the To/Cc/BCc field?

From [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47261/30106) I realize that I can create groups but it won't work for me as recipients keep changing in my case so grouping them would not be feasible. Also I have linked my social accounts so there are some email addresses which are coming from my social accounts but are not stored in my Gmail contacts.

I am using HTC One X with HTC Sense 5 and Android 4.2.2.